# 302 redirection for proxy calls to microservice with oauth2 behind zuul proxy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, oauth-2.0, netflix-zuul

I have one micro service "user-service". It is secured with spring-cloud-oauth2. It has one REST endpoint "/data/v1" which returns some JSON response.
When I send GET request to this endpoint it gets redirected to /oauth/login for authentication and after successful authentication it returns the token and then I am able to get the JSON response.

Later I added zuul proxy service ("micro-proxy-service") to route all external requests to internal back end services like "user-service".
It has single route "/resource" which then forwards the request to "/data/v1"
But now if I send GET requests to "/resource/data/v1" even after successful oauth2 authentication I get HTTP 302 response code with redirection to /login page.

If I try to access the "/data/v1" without zuul proxy then I am able to get response after oauth2. But when I request through zuul then I get 302.

If I remove the oauth2 from "user-service" then I can access "/data/v1" in both ways: directly or through zuul.

Please let me know If I am missing anything in zuul configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Zuul strips the authentication headers by default, to enable them use the following configuration

```
zuul: 
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```